# Is "impossibile" an adjective in "ad impossibile nemo tenetur"?

Tags: grammar-identification

In "ad impossibile nemo tenetur", is "impossibile" a noun derived from the adjective *impossibilis*, or just an adjective with the word *rem* implied?

Comment: *Res* is feminine, *impossibile* is neuter. Other than that, though, I don't think it's a meaningful distinction to make in general.

Comment: Agree with @Cairnarvon -- what difference does it make whether we call it a substantivized adjective or an adjective used substantively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pull together the comments into one answer: the term is adjectives used substantively (or some variation on that). You can read all the rules and get into the examples in [Allen and Greenough § 288](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/agreement-adjectives).

This a shared trait among IE languages, found in Latin, Greek, Sanskrit, and English, for example. Think only of English's "bring out your *dead*," where *dead*, an adjective in form, is being used as a noun.

This is so common you might not even have recognized it when translating *Romani in Italia habitant* as "Romans live in Italy" when both *Romani* and *Romans* are technically adjectives used substantively.

However, I'd caution against thinking that there is an implied *res*. For one, as Cairnarvon points out, *res* is feminine and *impossibile* is neuter. But though you can sometimes add *res* and make the adjective feminine and get the same result (*omnia* often meaning the same thing as *omnes res*), it won't always work. If ambiguity arises, it might need some other noun instead ("to an impossible *standard*"), a relative clause ("to that which is impossible"), or even swapped out entirely as an abstract noun, which in English we still can sometimes translate with a substantive adjective ("to the impossible").

And just like in the Latin, you couldn't add "thing" to the end of the last option and have it make sense. It's not "to the impossible thing", it is only "to the impossible."

Answer (score 1):

It is the first: an adjective used as a noun: that which is impossible. For example: *certum est quia impossibile* ("It is certain since it is impossible") --Tertullian.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong--but I would read your sample sentence as a pretty standard predicative adjective, not a substantivized adjective.

Comment: @brianpck maybe there is a better example

Comment: I would hesitate to say it is either one of the OP's alternatives, though. A substantivized adjective is arguably not a derivative but the adjective itself, and it could also be seen as having an omitted noun (not _res_ but a neuter one)...